FilePond not showing previews of loaded local existing pdf on laravel
I use FilePond to show displays existing data like image and pdf. When displaying images it works but when displaying pdf: Invalid PDF structure.
I saved the file in storage and run artisan storage command
this my code on controller
    $proposal = Proposal::find($id);
    if (!$proposal) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Proposal not found.');
    }
    $files = $proposal->files();
    $filePondFiles = Files::whereIn('id', json_decode($proposal->proposal_file_id))->get()->map(function ($file) {
        return [
            'source' => asset($file->file_path),
            'options' => [
                'type' => 'local',
                'metadata' => [
                    'poster' => asset($file->file_path)
                ], 
                'file' => [
                    'name' => $file->file_name,
                    'size' => $file->file_size,
                    'type' => $file->file_type,
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }); 

and this my script :
    // Register the plugins
FilePond.registerPlugin(
    FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
    FilePondPluginFileEncode,
    FilePondPluginFileValidateSize,
    FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation,
    FilePondPluginImagePreview,
    FilePondPluginPdfPreview,
    FilePondPluginFilePoster,
);

// Inisialisasi FilePond
const filePondElement = document.querySelector('input.filepond');
const initialFiles = @json($filePondFiles);
const pond = FilePond.create(filePondElement, {
    files: initialFiles,
    allowReorder: true,
    allowMultiple: true,
    acceptedFileTypes: [
        'application/msword',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
        'application/pdf',
        'image/*',
        'video/*',
        'audio/*',
    ],
    pdfPreviewHeight: 200,
    pdfComponentExtraParams: 'toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0',
    filePosterHeight: 150,
    labelFileTypeNotAllowed: 'File type not allowed',
    fileValidateTypeLabelExpectedTypes: 'Expects {allButLastType} or {lastType}',
});

